# Fixed effect in Pandas or Statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

Is there an existing function to estimate fixed effect (one-way or two-way) from Pandas or Statsmodels.

There used to be a function in Statsmodels but it seems discontinued. And in Pandas, there is something called `plm`, but I can't import it or run it using `pd.plm()`.

Comment: Please keep it to one question per question. Also, please explain what you mean by "i can't". Please include **full** tracebacks (if they exist) and a sample that is **small** and **runnable** *on its own* and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Also don't avoid telling us relevant information. "there used to be a function" implies you know what that function is, so why you avoid telling us confuses me.

Comment: @EMS Fixed effect is just a routine in my profession to control un-observable effect under assumption that these unobservables won't change over time. I am not with statistics, so I don't know nothing about a Bayesian's perspective..

Comment: @Veedrac Thanks for your suggestions. I don't see there are 2 questions because they are closely related. "I can't" simply means "I can't", because I can see `plm` in pandas source code, but **I cant't** find them out inside python.

Comment: @user3576212 Closely related is not the same as "the same". It's OK to have two closely related questions. Unless asking that would get closed as a duplicate of this, they are different questions.

Comment: @user3576212 "I can't" means lots of things. "I can't find it", "I can't run it", "I don't know how to use it", "I can't reproduce the documentation". If you just gave a one-line example and a traceback I wouldn't be asking for clarification.

Comment: @EMS what do you mean by "the theory behind it"? Is that something deeper and beyond a within transformation? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @EMS Even after not being a student anymore, econometricians still need to use them, see Klaus' and Jennifer's comments. I'm just reading both both Cameron/Trivedi and Wooldridge, again. (Not everybody has to buy into the assumptions of Bayesian multilevel models.)

Comment: @EMS Could you point out some `better` tools do you use to solve cross-sectional correlation other than Fama-Macbeth reg?

Comment: http://rfs.oxfordjournals.org/content/22/1/435.short

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to the `linearmodels` one, as pandas deprecated and dropped `PanelOLS` https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/pandas.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As noted in the comments, PanelOLS has been removed from Pandas as of version 0.20.0. So you really have three options:

1. If you use Python 3 you can use `linearmodels` as specified in the more recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44836199/3435183
2. Just specify various dummies in your `statsmodels` specification, e.g. using [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html). May not be feasible if the number of fixed effects is large.
3. Or do some groupby based demeaning and then use `statsmodels` (this would work if you're estimating lots of fixed effects). Here is a barebones version of what you could do for one way fixed effects:

   ```
   import statsmodels.api as sm
   import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
   import patsy

   def areg(formula,data=None,absorb=None,cluster=None): 

       y,X = patsy.dmatrices(formula,data,return_type='dataframe')

       ybar = y.mean()
       y = y -  y.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean') + ybar

       Xbar = X.mean()
       X = X - X.groupby(data[absorb]).transform('mean') + Xbar

       reg = sm.OLS(y,X)
       # Account for df loss from FE transform
       reg.df_resid -= (data[absorb].nunique() - 1)

       return reg.fit(cov_type='cluster',cov_kwds={'groups':data[cluster].values})
   ```

For example, suppose you have a panel of stock data: stock returns and other stock data for all stocks, every month over a number of months and you want to regress returns on lagged returns with calendar month fixed effects (where the calender month variable is called `caldt`) and you also want to cluster the standard errors by calendar month. You can estimate such a fixed effect model with the following:

```
reg0 = areg('ret~retlag',data=df,absorb='caldt',cluster='caldt')
```

And here is what you can do if using an older version of `Pandas`:

An example with time fixed effects using pandas' `PanelOLS` (which is in the plm module). Notice, the import of `PanelOLS`:

```
>>> from pandas.stats.plm import PanelOLS
>>> df

                y    x
date       id
2012-01-01 1   0.1  0.2
           2   0.3  0.5
           3   0.4  0.8
           4   0.0  0.2
2012-02-01 1   0.2  0.7 
           2   0.4  0.5
           3   0.2  0.3
           4   0.1  0.1
2012-03-01 1   0.6  0.9
           2   0.7  0.5
           3   0.9  0.6
           4   0.4  0.5
```

Note, the dataframe must have a multindex set ; `panelOLS` determines the `time` and `entity` effects based on the index:

```
>>> reg  = PanelOLS(y=df['y'],x=df[['x']],time_effects=True)
>>> reg

-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <x>

Number of Observations:         12
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   4

R-squared:         0.2729
Adj R-squared:     0.0002

Rmse:              0.1588

F-stat (1, 8):     1.0007, p-value:     0.3464

Degrees of Freedom: model 3, resid 8

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             x     0.3694     0.2132       1.73     0.1214    -0.0485     0.7872
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Docstring:

```
PanelOLS(self, y, x, weights = None, intercept = True, nw_lags = None,
entity_effects = False, time_effects = False, x_effects = None,
cluster = None, dropped_dummies = None, verbose = False,
nw_overlap = False)

Implements panel OLS.

See ols function docs
```

This is another function (like `fama_macbeth`) where I believe the plan is to move this functionality to `statsmodels`.

Comment: If you use the time index or group index `id` as a categorical variable in a formula for statsmodels ols, then it creates the fixed effects dummies for you. However, removing the fixed effects by demeaning is not yet supported.

Comment: @Karl D. Thanks a lot, your answers are always very useful!

Comment: Can I use random effects with pandas? I'm looking for something similar to stata's `xtreg, re`. Thanks!

Comment: Statsmodels will do random effects.

Comment: what is the difference between `time_effects` and  `entity_effects`?

Comment: @Moj, In a typical use case, your entity would be stocks, so `entity_effects` essentially creates dummy variable for each stock, and `time_effects` create dummy variables for every date.

Comment: when I'm reading tutorials on `fixed regression effects` they only introduce terms for entities to account for unobserved variables that are constant for each entity over time. Having 2 terms here confuses me a bit. can you point me to a source with good explanation? Thanks

Comment: and is there any documentation for `PanelOLS'`? I find nothing but a docstring

Comment: No, just the docstring, and it's unlikely to get any better documentation. `panelOLS` will probably be deprecated in `pandas` by 0.18: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6077.

Comment: Hi, @KarlD. I wonder if you could take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37194501/difference-in-differences-in-python-pandas?noredirect=1#comment61926329_37194501. I can't used this method and I don't know why. Thank you.

Comment: @KarlD. I have a question, I"m running this with my data set and the results are all 'nan'. Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: pandas dropped `PanelOLS` in 0.20.0 https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/pandas.html

Comment: Thanks, do you know if `linearmodels` is more efficient with large numbers of fixed effects than adding dummies is, as suggested in the post?

Comment: I haven't looked at their code but I imagine that `linearmodels` is approaching fixed effects like I do in option #3 in my outline above. That's going to be pretty efficient because it avoids doing matrix decomposition with very large matrices filled with dummy variables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the function from the 3rd option correctly. I understand that for data I'd include a df with the DV, all IVs/contros and the clusterID. for cluster I'd include `cluster = 'clusterID'`. But what does the `formula` and `absorb` part do? How do I make use of it?

Comment: `absorb` refers to the variable that contains the fixed effects: for example, a datetime column if you're estimating time fixed effects. The parameter naming comes for the areg function in `stata` and formula just refers to using `patsy` formula notation for a regression (statsmodels uses that too)

Comment: Does the order of the two indices in the Multi-index matter? I had to use `df = df.set_index(['entity', 'date'])` instead of `df = df.set_index(['date', 'entity'])` to make the PanelOLS work.

Comment: @KarlD. can you elaborate on your point 2. above using `pd.get_dummies()`. This would control for the fixed variables and one can then use good old OLS?

Comment: @oliver-angelil Yes, fixed effects models are equivalent to ols with explicit dummy variables. So, for example, if you're are estimating calendar month fixed effects, you need a dummy variable for each month.

Comment: Thanks @KarlD. Let's say I add the dummy variables for my fixed effects categorical variables, and also perform the normalisation (e.g. mean subtraction), can I use any regression model to fit to the data. I.e. does not need to be OLS, could be Random Forest regression?

Answer (score 25):

There is a package called `linearmodels` (https://pypi.org/project/linearmodels/) that has a fairly complete fixed effects and random effects implementation including clustered standard errors.  It does not use high-dimensional OLS to eliminate effects and so can be used with large data sets.

```
# Outer is entity, inner is time
entity = list(map(chr,range(65,91)))
time = list(pd.date_range('1-1-2014',freq='A', periods=4))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([entity, time])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(26*4, 2),index=index, columns=['y','x'])

from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
mod = PanelOLS(df.y, df.x, entity_effects=True)
res = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
print(res)
```

This produces the following output:

```
                          PanelOLS Estimation Summary                           
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                        0.0029
Estimator:                   PanelOLS   R-squared (Between):             -0.0109
No. Observations:                 104   R-squared (Within):               0.0029
Date:                Thu, Jun 29 2017   R-squared (Overall):             -0.0007
Time:                        23:52:28   Log-likelihood                   -125.69
Cov. Estimator:             Clustered                                           
                                        F-statistic:                      0.2256
Entities:                          26   P-value                           0.6362
Avg Obs:                       4.0000   Distribution:                    F(1,77)
Min Obs:                       4.0000                                           
Max Obs:                       4.0000   F-statistic (robust):             0.1784
                                        P-value                           0.6739
Time periods:                       4   Distribution:                    F(1,77)
Avg Obs:                       26.000                                           
Min Obs:                       26.000                                           
Max Obs:                       26.000                                           

                             Parameter Estimates                              
==============================================================================
            Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x              0.0573     0.1356     0.4224     0.6739     -0.2127      0.3273
==============================================================================

F-test for Poolability: 1.0903
P-value: 0.3739
Distribution: F(25,77)

Included effects: Entity
```

It also has a formula interface which is similar to statsmodels,

```
mod = PanelOLS.from_formula('y ~ x + EntityEffects', df)
```

Comment: Correct answer should be changed to this, because PanelOLS has been droped from pandas in 0.20 and I also cannot find it in statsmodels. https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/panel/pandas.html

Comment: Buyer beware: linearmodels requires Python 3.

Comment: Also, it does not make out of sample predictions. You have to code that yourself.

Comment: `linearmodels` also doesn't currently work with `stargazer` https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/issues/26

Comment: How to declare `entity` and `time`? i.e., how could this function know which variable is the `entity` and which is `time`? For those ran into this, check this:https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/examples/data-formats.html

Answer (score 0):

I have written a new package, [PyFixest](https://github.com/s3alfisc/pyfixest), that implements several routines for high dimensional fixed effects regression, following syntax innovations of the R package [fixest](https://github.com/lrberge/fixest). `PyFixest`supports OLS, IV and Poisson Regression with as many fixed effects as you'd want and a range of inference procedures (iid, HC1-3, CRV1 and CRV3 inference as well as the wild cluster bootstrap).

Here is a small code example:

```py
from pyfixest.estimation import feols
from pyfixest.utils import get_data

data = get_data()

# fit a model via OLS
fit = feols("Y ~ X1 | f1 + f2", data=data)
fit.summary()

# Estimation:  OLS
# Dep. var.: Y, Fixed effects: f1+f2
# Inference:  CRV1
# Observations:  997
# 
# | Coefficient   |   Estimate |   Std. Error |   t value |   Pr(>|t|) |   2.5 % # |   97.5 % |
# |:--------------|-----------:|-------------:|----------:|-----------:|--------:|---------:|
# | X1            |      0.292 |        0.040 |     7.256 |      0.000 |   0.210 |    0.374 |
# ---
# RMSE: 1.199   R2: 0.554   R2 Within: 0.037
```