# Pandas and PanelOLS: Only 2 level multiindex are supported

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I have a dataframe like this:

> ```
>      year   fcode        y        x
> 0    1987  410032       NaN       0
> 1    1988  410032       NaN       0
> 2    1989  410032       NaN       0
> 3    1987  410440       NaN       0
> 4    1988  410440       NaN       0
> 5    1989  410440       NaN       0
> 6    1987  410495       NaN       0
> 7    1988  410495       NaN       0
> 8    1989  410495       NaN       0
> 9    1987  410500       NaN       0
> 10   1988  410500       NaN       0
> 11   1989  410500       NaN       0
> 12   1987  410501       NaN       0
> 13   1988  410501       NaN       0
> 14   1989  410501       NaN       0
> 15   1987  410509       NaN       0
> 16   1988  410509       NaN       0
> 17   1989  410509       NaN       0
> 18   1987  410513       NaN       0
> 19   1988  410513       NaN       0
> 20   1989  410513       NaN       0
> 21   1987  410517       NaN       0
> 22   1988  410517       NaN       0
> 23   1989  410517       NaN       0
> 24   1987  410518       NaN       0
> 25   1988  410518       NaN       0
> 26   1989  410518       NaN       0
> 27   1987  410521       NaN       0
> 28   1988  410521       NaN       0
> 29   1989  410521       NaN       0
> ..    ...     ...       ...     ...
> 441  1987  419450       NaN       0
> 442  1988  419450       NaN       0
> 443  1989  419450       NaN       0
> 444  1987  419459  0.512824       0
> 445  1988  419459  0.916291       0
> 446  1989  419459  0.113329       0
> ```

I have sorted by `year` and `fcode`:

```
df.sort_index(by=['year','fcode'])
```

I droped missing data:

```
df = df.dropna() # Drop missing
```

I got this:

```
     year   fcode         y       x
30  1987  410523 -2.813411      0
48  1987  410538  0.970779      0
75  1987  410563  1.791759      0
81  1987  410565  3.044523      0
84  1987  410566  1.945910      0
87  1987  410567  0.000000      0
96  1987  410577  0.518794      0
105 1987  410592  3.401197      0
108 1987  410593  0.000000      0
111 1987  410596  2.302585      0
120 1987  410606 -0.415515      0
129 1987  410626 -0.139262      0
135 1987  410629  0.182322      0
159 1987  410653  0.058269      0
162 1987  410665 -2.995732      0
171 1987  410685 -1.966113      0
186 1987  418011  2.302585      0
195 1987  418021  0.000000      0
201 1987  418035  1.791759      0
207 1987  418045  0.693147      0
213 1987  418051 -0.798508      0
219 1987  418054  0.223143      0
222 1987  418065  0.262364      0
228 1987  418076  0.058269      0
231 1987  418083  1.098612      0
237 1987  418091  2.101692      0
240 1987  418097  0.512824      0
246 1987  418107 -0.020203      0
252 1987  418118  0.000000      0
258 1987  418125 -0.798508      0
...          ...       ...    ...
233 1989  418083  0.000000      0
239 1989  418091 -0.579819      0
242 1989  418097  0.350657      0
248 1989  418107 -0.798508      0
254 1989  418118 -2.302585      0
260 1989  418125 -0.510826      0
266 1989  418140  0.916291      0
272 1989  418163  1.871802      0
275 1989  418168 -1.609438      0
278 1989  418177  2.890372      0
299 1989  418237 -1.660731      0
311 1989  419198  1.386294      0
314 1989  419201  0.693147      0
317 1989  419242  1.740466      0
320 1989  419268 -0.105360      1
323 1989  419272  2.833213      1
332 1989  419289 -0.051293      1
335 1989  419297 -1.309333      0
350 1989  419307 -0.116534      1
368 1989  419339 -0.798508      0
371 1989  419343  1.098612      1
383 1989  419357 -0.693147      1
392 1989  419378  0.292670      1
401 1989  419381 -0.967584      1
407 1989  419388  1.791759      1
422 1989  419409  0.693147      1
431 1989  419432  1.648659      0
446 1989  419459  0.113329      0
464 1989  419482  1.029619      0
467 1989  419483  3.401197      0
```

I try to run this:

```
model  = pd.stats.plm.PanelOLS(y=df['y'],x=df[['x']],time_effects=True)
```

I get this error:

> raise NotImplementedError('Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.')
>       NotImplementedError: Only 2-level MultiIndex are supported.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. You can see that it seems my code is similar to [Fixed effects in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195432/fixed-effect-in-pandas-or-statsmodels)

When I add

```
df=df.set_index('year', append=True)
```

I get

```
Degrees of Freedom: model 161, resid 0

    -----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
          Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             x     0.0000        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
```

Comment: Maybe you add column to index - `df=df.set_index('year', append=True)` - result is df with `multiindex`

Comment: Thank you! The error has gone away, but I believe there are still problems, since I am finding a model with all statistics null. See the edition above, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
print df.head()
    year   fcode         y  x
30  1987  410523 -2.813411  0
48  1987  410538  0.970779  0
75  1987  410563  1.791759  0
81  1987  410565  3.044523  0
84  1987  410566  1.945910  0

#convert year to datetime
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y')
#add column year to index
df=df.set_index('year', append=True)
#swap indexes
df.index = df.index.swaplevel(0,1)
print df.head()
                fcode         y  x
year                              
1987-01-01 30  410523 -2.813411  0
           48  410538  0.970779  0
           75  410563  1.791759  0
           81  410565  3.044523  0
           84  410566  1.945910  0

model  = pd.stats.plm.PanelOLS(y=df['y'],x=df[['x']],time_effects=True)
```

```
print model
-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <x>

Number of Observations:         60
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   3

R-squared:         0.0013
Adj R-squared:    -0.0338

Rmse:              1.4727

F-stat (1, 57):     0.0364, p-value:     0.8493

Degrees of Freedom: model 2, resid 57

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             x     0.1539     0.5704       0.27     0.7882    -0.9640     1.2719
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! What does it mean df.index = df.index.swaplevel(0,1)?

Comment: It is strange for me that the degree of freedom goes to 60-3. In the typical fixed effect panel data model it goes to N(T-1)-K.

Comment: `swaplevel` - it swap first level of multiindex with second level one, because you need first level of multiindex `year`. [Doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#swapping-levels-with-swaplevel)

Comment: Why is it necessary to have a multi index?