# How can I run a diff-in-diff with fixed effects in Python?

Tags: python, panel-data

I tried searching everywhere, but couldn't find this: how can I run a diff-in-diff with fixed effects in Python?

I already know how to run a diff-in-diff. For instance, let's consider the [njmin](http://www.principlesofeconometrics.com/poe4/data/excel/njmin3.xlsx) dataset. This dataset consider the minimum wage increase in New Jersey. First of all, sorry about the screenshots, I know it's not recommended, but I think it will be a facilitator in here. Here, we are talking about the minimum wage increase and its effects in the unemployment rate. More about the problem you can find in [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/identify-causality-by-difference-in-differences-78ad8335fb7c). I ran a ols regression to see if **d_nj**, which is the result of the multiplication of **d** (after minimum wage increase) and **nj** (if in New Jersey), has any effect on **fte**, which is **full-time equivalent employees**. Basically, we want to know if the change in the minimum wage affected the unemployment.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf 
import statsmodels.api as sm  
df = pd.read_csv('/njmin3.csv')

model = smf.ols(formula = "fte ~ d_nj + kfc + roys + wendys \
      + CO_OWNED + SOUTHJ + CENTRALJ + PA1", data = df).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

[image]

As you can see, we have a diff-in-diff model to see if the minimum wage increase in New Jersey had impact in the unemployment rate. **d_nj** was not significant.

Now, if I have many cities, many datapoints, and want to include fixed effects. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`linearmodels`](https://pypi.org/project/linearmodels/) library. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44836199/327165) and `linearmodels` [docs](https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/doc/).